# Caliburn.micro, SplitView and navigation

Tags: wpf, windows-phone, caliburn.micro, uwp

I have a question about Caliburn.Micro NavigationService and UWP SplitView control.

There are example of *first-level navigation* with SplitView : https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/tree/3.0.0/samples/Caliburn.Micro.HelloUWP

In this example NavigationService tied to Frame in Content part of SplitView. How can I open new Page without SplitView, i.e. implement *second-level navigation*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the 'best' way, but what I did, was add a `ViewModel` to the ShellView that holds a list of all Page types I don't want a SplitView available.

Then I register for the OnNavigated event of the frame inside the SplitView and each time this event is fired I trigger a method on the ViewModel behind the ShellView.

In that method I switch the type of the SplitView control from Overlay to Inline and set the property IsOpen to false. This way it's completely hidden for the user.

Detailed code ( but not using Caliburn ) can be found here:
https://github.com/AppCreativity/Kliva/blob/master/Kliva/Controls/KlivaApplicationFrame.cs
https://github.com/AppCreativity/Kliva/blob/master/Kliva/ViewModels/SidePaneViewModel.cs

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this method does not work well with adaptive SplitView , when it DisplayMode and IsPaneOpen properties controlled by VisualStates. After changing screen orientation(or resizing window, for example) SplitView properties are overwriting. Of cource, I can control VisualStates from c# code. But I think this is not right way

Comment: Yeah that is true... But I'm binding those properties through MVVM so you can add extra logic in the setters/getters to ensure the correct value is set even though they are changed through visual states